# Git - Change the file in one branch back to original in main

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and have a `package.json` file in branch (let's call it branch1). I want to change this file back to the original one in the main branch.

I tried `git checkout package.json main` which didn't work.

Comment: Branch name goes first.

Comment: One good practice is also to always give filepaths at the end, after `--`, like `-- <filepath> [<filepath2> ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's alright, git's hard! I believe you're looking for [restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore).

> Restore specified paths in the working tree with some contents from a restore source. If a path is tracked but does not exist in the restore source, it will be removed to match the source.

Specifically try:

`git restore --source main package.json`